# Unexpected behavior in list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I want to find positions of zeros in a list.

```
mylist = [0, 1 ,False,2, 0.0, 'a', 0]

all_items=[i for i in enumerate(mylist)]
# all_items=  [(0, 0), (1, 1), (2, False), (3, 2), (4, 0.0), (5, 'a'), (6, 0)]    
    
res1=[]
for i in enumerate(mylist):
    if i[1] is 0 or i[1] is 0.0:
        res1.extend([i])

# res1 =[(0, 0), (4, 0.0), (6, 0)] 

res2=[i for i in enumerate(mylist) if i[1] is 0 or i[1] is 0.0]

#res2=[(0, 0), (6, 0)]
```

I supposed `res1` and `res2` to be equivalent, but they differs. Why `0.0` is not in `res2`?

Comment: Use `==` rather than `is`

Comment: What is the `all_items` variable for? You never use it.

Comment: FYI, `[i for i in something]` can be simplified to just `list(something)`. And `res1.extend([i])` should be `res1.append(i)`

Comment: I get the same result from the `for` loop and the list comprehension. I had to change from `mylist` to `Mylist`.

Comment: Just try `print(all_items[4][1] is 0.0)` and you'll see that it's not true.

Comment: Ok, `all_items[4][1] is 0.0` is `False`, then why `0.0` in `res1` ?

Comment: It isn't in `res1` when I try it.

Comment: Comparing identity (is) and equality (==) are different things. The former is stronger than the later. It is equal and the same object.

Comment: Hmm, I get your results when I try it on ideone.com. Maybe the difference is that I did my test in the REPL rather than running a script.

Comment: It seems like it has something to do with optimizations done when compiling the script, related to how `is` is compiled in the two contexts. But you shouldn't depend on `is` this way,.

Comment: I've tried it in my IDE and here [link](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_python_interpreter). Python ver. 3.7 and 3.4. And got the same results. `res1` and `res2` are different.

Comment: Thank you, @Barmar! I know that it is better to use `==` instead `is`, but I cant understand the reason of different behavior. You pointed the reason.